# How to log the method name in Log4net using the 'InfoFormat' method?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

When I used the Info or Debug methods of log4net it logs the method name as one of the fields.

However, when I use the InfoFormat or any of the other format methods, it does not log the method name. Is it possible to log the method name as well, using the format methods? If so, how?

Presently, it just fills that column with a question mark.

Edit: A line in the log looks like

`INFO  2015-04-11 02:30:45,254  2074ms className  ? - Some logging info`

It contains the following information:

1.Debugging level

2.Date

3.Time

4.Time since program began execution

5.Class Name

6.Method name - This is displaying a question mark. I want it to display the method name

7.Logging information

Comment: Please show your config

Comment: @stuartd I am also facing same problem. Problem is that I don't get method name when using DebugFormat(..) while I am getting it in using Debug(..)

Answer (score -1):

In your pattern layout you can access the method name with the `%M` (note uppercase) or `%method` variables.
See the [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) documentation for a list.
It's worth noting, that using location info variables can be slow.